# What is the total amount each customer spent at the restaurant? Not able to see different customer_id.. shows only one same id for all amounts

Tags: mysql, group-by, count, inner-join

Query

```
select customer_id ,(numbers*price) as amount 
from (select *,  count(s.product_id) as numbers
      from sales s group by product_id) as sub1 
inner join
( select s.product_id, price 
  from menu m inner join sales s on m.product_id = s.product_id 
  group by product_id) as sub2 on sub1.product_id = sub2.product_id;
```

sample data :

```
INSERT INTO sales ("customer_id", "order_date", "product_id") 
VALUES ('A', '2021-01-01', '1'),('A', '2021-01-01', '2'),('A', '2021-01-07', '2'),('A', '2021-01-10', '3'),('A', '2021-01-11', '3'),('A', '2021-01-11', '3'),('B', '2021-01-01', '2'),('B', '2021-01-02', '2'),('B', '2021-01-04', '1'),('B', '2021-01-11', '1'),('B', '2021-01-16', '3'),('B', '2021-02-01', '3'),('C', '2021-01-01', '3'),('C', '2021-01-01', '3'),('C', '2021-01-07', '3'); 

INSERT INTO menu ("product_id", "product_name", "price") 
VALUES ('1', 'sushi', '10'),('2', 'curry', '15'),('3', 'ramen', '12');
```

Output

```
customer_id   amount
A              30
A              60
A              96
```

whereas i want it to show A,B,C as customer ids as the amount is calculated correctly for them. Its showing A as customer_id for all three as first three ids in sales table are for customer A.
I tried group by with customer id as well.. it shows only one result, i.e. A and 30.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: please check https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so- and also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query when-asking-a-question and produce a [mre]

Comment: please provide sample data & desired output

Comment: @AbhayTyagi please add also the data that produces that result and also which result you expect, whna you add it a dbfiddle.uk helpsalso

Comment: Remember, you can always delete comments, and edit questions

Answer (score 0):

seems like you want sales report per product :

```
select  product_name, sum(price) amount
from sales s
join menu m on s.product_id = m.product_id
group by product_name
order by sum(price)
```

> | product_name | amount |
> | --- | --- |
> | sushi | 30 |
> | curry | 60 |
> | ramen | 96 |

but if you want total sale per customer :

```
select  customer_id , sum(price) amount
from sales s
join menu m on s.product_id = m.product_id
group by customer_id
order by customer_id
```

> | customer_id | amount |
> | --- | --- |
> | A | 76 |
> | B | 74 |
> | C | 36 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dafc060d9957f9ecc460631597e15f3f)*